# how to loop on all sub lists and compare each element with python

Tags: python-3.x

How to compare multiple list items with each other and provide results?

```
X = [10 20 50 100 500 400]

Y = [30 20 60 70 90 490]
```

Compare `X[0]` which is 10 with `Y[0]` which is 30 and check which list has greater number after comparing each element.

How can we achieve this in python3x?

Comment: What's the logic behind declaring one array greater than the other? Do all elements have to be greater or most?

Comment: X[1] and Y[1] are the same.

Comment: The description is ambiguous. Is a list larger than another only if all elements are larger? All elements are greater than or equal to? More elements are greater than are less? The sum of the elements is greater?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try something like the code below:

```
>>> x = 10, 20, 50, 100, 500, 400
>>> y = 30, 20, 60, 70, 90, 490
>>> for index, (x_value, y_value) in enumerate(zip(x, y)):
        sign = '>' if x_value > y_value else '<' if x_value < y_value else '=='
        print(f'x[{index}] {sign} y[{index}]')
```

If you try running the code, it will produce the following output:

```
x[0] < y[0]
x[1] == y[1]
x[2] < y[2]
x[3] > y[3]
x[4] > y[4]
x[5] < y[5]
```

If that is not what you are asking for, then you will want to clarify your question.

---

**Addendum:**

You really should ask a new question for your modified scenario, but here is an extended answer:

```
>>> x = [[112, 243, 512, 343, 90, 478], [40, 50, 60, 70, 80]]
>>> y = [[500, 789, 234, 400, 452, 150], [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]]
>>> for index_1, (row_x, row_y) in enumerate(zip(x, y)):
        for index_2, (value_x, value_y) in enumerate(zip(row_x, row_y)):
            print(f'x[{index_1}][{index_2}] {">" if value_x > value_y else "<" if value_x < value_y else "="} y[{index_1}][{index_2}]')
```

The code up above should produce the following output:

```
x[0][0] < y[0][0]
x[0][1] < y[0][1]
x[0][2] > y[0][2]
x[0][3] < y[0][3]
x[0][4] < y[0][4]
x[0][5] > y[0][5]
x[1][0] > y[1][0]
x[1][1] > y[1][1]
x[1][2] > y[1][2]
x[1][3] > y[1][3]
x[1][4] > y[1][4]
```

Comment: Your answer is correct as per question but if suppose i've multiple lists as follows x = [[112,243,512,343,90,478],[40,50,60,70,80]]
y = [[500,789,234,400,452,150],[10,20,30,40,50]] and now i want to compare each element than how to do it ?

Comment: @Vimal The answer has been modified per your request.

Answer (score 0):

Try a nested for-loop and compare each element, if I read your question correct. Please Google "nested for loop" to look into what I am referring to. It may help you.